# How can I get on the tunnel roof by MCOM A on Grand Bazaar Rush?

Tags: battlefield-3

I've recently played a number of games of Rush on Grand Bazaar and when attacking I manage to run along the left tunnel, go to arm the MCOM and then get mowed down by people camping above the tunnel exit (circled below).
[image]

Is this hack to get up there or is there a legitamite way of doing so? Once one person gets up there his squadmates can spawn on him and put a beacon down so they don't have to worry about getting up there again.

Comment: My guess: They used a truck (or other vehicle) as boost to get up there.

Comment: @5pike at this stage of the name, there are no vehicles. The static map vehicles are too far away to be any use.

Comment: Oh ok. I saw a few videos where they used vehicles to access high places. Here is [one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPfMDiLNQvM). At 3:50, you can see them using a tree. In your screenshot, there's also a tree nearby. Could be, that they used that.

Comment: @5pike ah the tree climb is the most likely idea - when I next see it happen I'll see if the tree has gone or not.

Comment: There are several places on Grand Bazaar that I've used trees to climb to. usually it involves knocking over the tree so you can "run" up it. Never done it in that spot, but I bet that's how they're getting up there